# write an sql or block generate below result set for below scenario

Tags: mysql

```
Table1
Name typeofcontract  amount
Ajay    Account -2000
Ajay    Loan    5000
Ajay    Deposit 11000
Aman    Deposit 12000
Aman    Loan    5000
Aman    Account 2000
```

Need to generate a result set using SQL as follows

```
Name  noofaccount Noofloan Noofdeposit borrowedamount  availamount  total amount
Ajay   1         1      1              7000            11000        6000
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Firstly, please be polite and ask a question. Do not structure the question as a demand. What SQL have you attempted? It is always best to post a snippet from your attempts rather than asking the community to provide a blue-sky solution. [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
SELECT Name,
    SUM(IF(typeofcontract='Account') THEN 1 ELSE 0) NoOfAccount,
    SUM(IF(typeofcontract='Loan') THEN 1 ELSE 0) NoOfLoan,
    SUM(IF(typeofcontract='Deposit') THEN 1 ELSE 0) NoOfDeposit,
    SUM(IF(typeofcontract='Account') THEN amount * -1
        ELSE IF (typeofcontract='Loan') THEN amount) BorrowedAmount,
    SUM(IF(typeofcontract='Deposit') THEN amount) AvailableAmount,
    SUM(IF(typeofcontract='Deposit') THEN amount
        ELSE IF (typeofcontract='Loan') THEN amount * -1) TotalAmount
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Name
```

Check the logic for the calculated amounts because it is not definite from your example. This should give you an approach on how to solve this kind of problems. There are other ways possible to get this output.